# jQuery.prop() does not modify DOM element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, dom-events

I use an input field to submit 2 pieces of data to an event handler: the displayed value and a property value.

When I populate the data, I do this:

```
      xInput.val('ARC'+opts[0].arc);
      xInput.prop('data-sine',opts[0].sine);
// Now, trigger submit-handler
      xInput.show();
      xInput.trigger('change');
```

When I stop in the debugger, I can see that the property `data-sine` exists on the jQuery object and has the correct data.

Now, in the change event, I want to move the data from the "element" onto the event so the astrosearch API invocation can pick it up using a generic event handler, which also handles input from a `<SELECT>` tag in cases where there is more than one arc to choose from. So, I do this:

```
    xInput.on('change', function (e) { 
      e.sine = $(this).attr('data-sine');
      astrofinder.findAstro(e, true);
      astrofinder.ui.countdown.start(function () { xInput.trigger('find'); }); 
    });
```

When I stop at the first line here, `this` is NOT the `xInput` jQuery object, it's the raw HTML element - BUT the element *DOES NOT HAVE* a `data-sine` property!  Somehow, it didn't make it out of jQuery into the DOM?

Why?  Do I need to use a timer to get into the next event loop?

Comment: Of course, I know the workaround is to just do `e.sine = xInput.prop('data-sine')` but that just side-steps the real question - why isn't the prop available (via DOM) to code that doesn't have access to the `xInput` jQuery instance?

Comment: Try to populate using `xInput.attr('data-sine',opts[0].sine);`

Comment: There is a big difference between element *properties* and *attributes*. `value` is a perfect example. The value attribute is not synchronized with value property after initial page load. You are setting a *property* and trying to read as *attribute*

Comment: OMG. @charlietfl you nailed it. Attributes are the ones that appear as part of the HTML element, not sure where properties go. Either way, my code was internally inconsistent. Thank you!

Comment: DOM = Document Object Model. Each node in document is an object that has *properties*. In some cases those properties are based on attributes found in the html when loaded. `<input value="foo"/>` gets processed to the value property for example allowing you to access it as `inputElement.value`

Comment: @charlietfl Yeah, I got that from your first comment. But this begs the real question - when should one use `prop` and when `attr`? For this case, either works as well (as long as I'm consistent) but what are the reasons to use an object property vs. a DOM attribute? One obvious reason: adding an attribute can affect the display but a property wouldn't. Is the property available via the `event.target` like an attribute would be? Are there other factors/benefits/side-effects?

Comment: Should find plenty of results in  search for jQuery attr vs prop as well as in the docs

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr was an excellent read.